# Django send_mass_email without showing all recipients' Emails

Tags: django

Using `send_mass_mail` will result in all the emails being shown in the 'To' field.

I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088069/send-mass-mail-with-hidden-recipients) but it hides all user Emails.  And it looks weird in the inbox because the 'To' field is empty.

What I want is to use `send_mass_mail` showing only the receiving recipient's Email in the 'To' field.  E.g. If I send Emails to jack@gmail.com and jane@gmail.com, jack should see jack@gmail.com and jane should see jane@gmail.com in the 'To' field.

Is there a way to achieve this?  Or do I have to use loop over each recipient with `send_mail`?

Comment: I don't know of a solution besides iterating over each recipient. But as far as I know, mass mailing lists all use BCC, so it seems to be the standard practice.

Comment: @Ralf Right.  I guess I will just use the iteration method until the mailing list gets too big.

Answer (score 1):

You can send separate emails directly to different recipients using [send_mass_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail), you just need to get the arguments structured properly:

```
message1 = ('Subject here', 'Here is the message', 'from@example.com', ['first@example.com', 'other@example.com'])
message2 = ('Another Subject', 'Here is another message', 'from@example.com', ['second@test.com'])
send_mass_mail((message1, message2), fail_silently=False)
```

This is not too different from iterating over the recipients yourself and sending each email separately, except for one key difference; using send_mass_email will result in all emails being sent via a single connection to your mail server. Doing it iteratively in your code will result in connections being opened and closed for each email and as a result will be slower due to that overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail

subject = 'test subject'
message = 'test message'
from_email = 'from@from.com'
recipient_list = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com']

messages = [(subject, message, from_email, [recipient]) for recipient in recipient_list]

send_mass_mail(messages)
```